# to show $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i y_i|$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, self-learning

$X$ consists of sets of the form $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$ where $x_i \in \mathbb R$.

Suppose $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i ^2$ converges.

Show that : $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i y_i$| converges. where $x,y \in X$

I am able to show that $|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i y_i| \le [\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i^2]^\frac12 *[\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} y_i^2]^\frac12$ (using cauchy schwarz)

So $|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i y_i|$ converges. But how to bring mod sign inside $\sum$ so that I can show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i y_i|$ converges .

Comment: CS gives that $\sum |x_i||y_i|\le \dots$.

Comment: I would consider $(|x_i|+|y_i|)^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Cauchy schwarz says that: $|<x,y>|^2 \le ||x||.||y||$. Hence the LHS will come out to be $|\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i y_i|$ and NOT $\sum |x_i||y_i|$

Comment: I am using CS on the absolute values.

Comment: @EricTowers $\sum (|x_i| +|y_i|)^2 = \sum x_i^2 + \sum y_i^2 + 2\sum|x_iy_i|$..
then what??

Comment: In the first two lines you could be more clear in that $X=\ell^2$, that is, the convergence of the series of squares is a defining property for $X$. As it is, the text does not make any claim on $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |y_k|^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz gives that $\sum_1^n |x_i||y_i|\le (\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^{1/2}(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2)^{1/2}$. And absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: This would be more impossible-to-miss if $x_i$ and $y_i$ were each wrapped in two sets of absolute value brackets.  (... without looking like norm brackets...)  Otherwise, this inequality does not transparently match that of C-S-B.

Comment: It is the CS Inequality for $|x_i|$, $|y_i|$. On the right I did not write $|x_i|^2$, settling for the equivalent $x_i^2$.

Comment: Not arguing.  Just helping any reader whose eyes did not see that the RHS contains $\left| \ \left| x_i \right| \ \right|^2$ and similarly for $y_i$.